# Android Studio build error: AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"ERROR: Asset package includ

Tags: android, android-studio

I occurred build error:

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"ERROR: Asset package include \u0027D:\\AndroidSDK\\android-sdk-windows\\platforms\\android-23\\android.jar\u0027 not found.","sources":[{}]}
```

within Android Studio(D:\AndroidSDK\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-23\android.jar is the path I replace original Android's android.jar with my customized android.jar). 
The strange parts are

```
1.The android.jar did exist under the path
2.The project "sometimes" build pass(apk generated) but found the error mentioned above most of the time.
```

Is someone had occurred the same problem?